# Unable to use order and limit in Datatables server side using SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, datatables

I am encountering issue transferring my datatable server-side code from MySQL to SQL server. I have managed to display the output if I remove this particular line in the server side.

$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

But the issue is I can't order and limit the number of items appearing. How will I make this code work in SQL server? Please, any assistance would be a great help. Thank you

Here is my complete code for server side

```
 <?php require_once("../includes/connection.php");



$connection = sqlsrv_connect(DB_HOST, array( 'Database'=>DB_NAME, 'UID'=>DB_USER, 'PWD'=>DB_PASSWORD,"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"));

    // /* Database connection end */

    if( $connection ) {

        }else{
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }




// // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 =>'new_id', 
    1 => 'person_name',
    2=> 'given_name',
    3=> 'family_name'



);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * , user.id as new_id  ";
$sql.=" FROM user LEFT JOIN user_additional on user.doc_id = user_additional.doc_id  LEFT JOIN users on users.id = user.user_name";
$query=sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql) ;

if( $query === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$totalData = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql ="SELECT * , user.id as new_id  ";
$sql.=" FROM user LEFT JOIN user_additional on user.doc_id = user_additional.doc_id  LEFT JOIN users on users.id = user.user_name WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter

$sql.=" AND ( person_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
$sql.=" OR family_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";

$sql.=" OR given_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql) ;

if( $query === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$totalFiltered = sqlsrv_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 




$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";


/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */    
$query=sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql) ;

if( $query === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$data = array();
while( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    // $nestedData[]="";
    $nestedData[] = $row["new_id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["person_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["given_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["family_name"];



    ;



    $data[] = $nestedData;
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

Comment: SELECT TOP n in SQL Server is the equivalent to limit in mysql.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sql server 2012 or above you could use `OFFSET/FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY` clause. Sample query for your reference:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Dept
  FROM Employee
  order by Id asc
  offset 100 rows
  fetch next 10 rows only
```

Please try after modifying your code to build query as above. [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1001614/Using-OFFSET-and-FETCH-with-the-ORDER-BY-clause)

Comment: Hi, I've modified it works when I put static data in 100 in order by but when I put variables in it does not work in SQL server datatables. Any thoughts? 
` $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  offset ".$requestData['start']."  fetch next  ".$requestData['length']." rows only  "; '

Comment: Can you print $sql and share the sql generated?